# Why Microsoft does not use Entity Framework on their products?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, servicebus, workflow-manager-1.x

I was wondering why Microsoft doesn't use Entity framework on their products like Service Bus, Workflow Manager, and BizTalk and so on?

Since they are pushing.NET communities to use it, why they don't start the initiative and show us the best practice on how we can, as a .NET stack developer, to implement enterprise project using EF best practice?

Is that related to the performance issue the people talk about since the very release of EF?

Comment: A sample of huge no of stored procedures used in Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 http://i.imgur.com/mKDGaML.png

Answer (score 2):

EF has come a long way since early versions of ORM. I have used in some very large projects and haven't had any significant performance issues. That said, products that you have mentioned have been there before EF came into existence so they may have some form of ORM which could have been build and maintained internally. If you are looking for some good pattern and practices please checkout some [articles](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/) written by *Julie Lerman*.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However, the products I refered to in my questions are considred new product. If I wasn't mistaken, both Service Bus and Workflow Manager were released around 2011-2014, which means that the EF was already there (I think it was EF 4.0 - 4.1).